# passsing datagridview values directly to first form

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

i have Form1 ,Form2 ,Form3. form2 is opened from form1 and form3 is opened from form2,in form3 i have 3 dgv , when filled a button is hiding form3 and buttoon to hide form2 to reach form1 and then click save to insert rows from dgv in form3 to database.
i tried to code it but i dont know how to access dgv directly and iterate each row like this :

```
using (Form3 frm3 = new Form3())
{


    cmd1.CommandText = "insert into [dbo].[personClothesDesc](upperPart, lowerPart, belt, socks, shoes, differentSigns) values (@upperPart, @lowerPart, @belt, @socks, @shoes, @differentSigns)";
    for (int i = 0; i < form3.dataGridView3.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        cmd1.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@upperPart", dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lowerPart", dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@belt", dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@socks", dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shoes", dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@differentSigns", dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

cmd1.CommandText = "insert into [dbo].[personGeneralDesc](gender, age, height, bodyType, skinColor, differentSigns) values (@gender, @age, @height, @bodyType, @skinColor, @differentSigns)";
for (int i = 0; i < form3.dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    cmd1.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@height", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bodyType", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@skinColor", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@differentSigns", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

cmd1.CommandText = "insert into [dbo].[personHeadDesc](headShape, faceShape, eyesShape, hairType, chinType, eyeGlasses, headCoverUp, differentSigns) values (@headShape, @faceShape, @eyesShape, @hairType, @chinType, @eyeGlasses, @headCoverUp, @differentSigns)";
for (int i = 0; i < form3.dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    cmd1.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@height", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bodyType", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@skinColor", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@differentSigns", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this `using (Form3 frm3= new Form3())` ?

Comment: even if write Form3 frm3 = new Form3(); its not working

Comment: this doesn't open Form3 !

Comment: its giving me an error :
index was out of range . must be non negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name = index

Comment: i opened form3 from another button,values are kept in dgv when filled in Form3, when i get back to Form1 ,I click save and insert the values in dgv in Form3 to database

Comment: Make sure that your cell range in use really goes from 1 to 6, otherwise would be from 0 to 5

Comment: yeah its from 1 to 6